# Update input in module with dynamic number of ui elements

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write a module with a dynamic number **n**, say,  of UI elements. I observed that the `input` slot does **not** correspond with current number of elements but the largest number chosen during the session:

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)

testUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("container"))
}

test <- function(input, output, session, numElems) {
   output$container <- renderUI(do.call(tagList, llply(1:numElems(), function(i) 
            selectInput(session$ns(paste0("elem", i)), 
                        label = i, choices = LETTERS[sample(26, 3)]))))
   getNames <- reactive(reactiveValuesToList(input))
   list(getNames = getNames)
}

ui <- fluidPage(numericInput("n", "Number of Elems", value = 3), 
                testUI("column1"), 
                verbatimTextOutput("debug"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   getN <- reactive(input$n)
   handler <- callModule(test, "column1", getN)
   output$debug <- renderPrint(handler$getNames())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you change the number of elements in the numeric input field from `3` to `2`, we see that there are still `3` elements in `input`. Is this behaviour intentional? If so, how can I update the `input` to asure that it only contains valid slots?

**Update**

Here are the 2 relevant screenshots:

[image: 3 Products selected]

[image: 2 Products selected]

Comment: Interesting. I would suggest adding a screenshot. Might be worth filing as a bug, then someone would have to think about whether or not it is desired behavior.

Comment: looks like the ui element created will not be deleted by shiny, but keeps re-using. Guess this will not affect the user experience, as for shiny programmer, we can restrict the access to the elements related to "Number of elements" by checking the element id.

Comment: In case you didnt know it, there is a similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678358/how-to-delete-an-input-in-shiny-renderui. Probably you know already the workaround: handler$getNames()[1:input$n]. Would be interesting indeed, if input can be updated in the way you need it.

Comment: @TonioLiebrand thanks for the pointer to this other discussion. As for the workaround: is it assured that new elements will always be added to the end of `input`? Because when playing with the code above you will see that if you ask for >10 elements it seems that ? `input` will be sorted according to `names(input)`? (try yourself: ask for 11 elements and then for 3 and observe the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's 6 years since the OP asked this question but here are my two cents regarding the topic.

### TL;DR

> Is this behaviour intentional?

I don't know. But it is *consistent*. You use `renderUI` in your example, I use `insertUI`/`removeUI` in my reprex below, and the behaviour is the same.

> How can I update the `input` to assure that it only contains valid slots?

You can set the "invalid" slots to `NULL`, then use `req()` or `isTruthy()` to check for validity.

### Explanation

Here's what I know so far about `input`:

1. `input` is immutable from the app's server, unless you use `update*Input()`

eg. If you try:

```r
input$random_id <- "trial"
```

you will get an error: `Can't modify read-only reactive value 'random_id'`.

2. Once added, you can't remove an element (an input id) from `input`, but you can change its value (Using `update*Input()` or JavaScript)
3. Changing the value of an element to `NULL` will not remove it from `input`.

By that I mean `input` will not behave like a regular list where setting the value of an element to `NULL` removes it from the list:

```r
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
x$a <- NULL
x

# $b
# [1] 2
#
# $c
# [1] 3
```

Also, you can't use `update*Input()` to set the value of an input id to `NULL`. From `?updateSelectInput`:

> Any arguments with `NULL` values will be ignored; they will not result in any changes to the input object on the client.

So to set the value of an `input` element to `NULL` you have to use JavaScript and provide the option `priority: "event"`. [Reference](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/communicating-with-js/).

```js
Shiny.setInputValue(input_id, new_input_value, {priority: "event"})
```

4. We can use `3` above to our advantage: Set the unwanted elements (input id values whose UI has been removed/deleted) to `NULL`.

This allows us to use `req()` or `isTruthy()` if need be.

### Reprex

In the reprex below, I show how you can set the input id values to `NULL`.

[image: input-reprex-showcase]

#### global.R

```r
library(shiny)
```

#### ui.R

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("n", "Number of Elems", value = 3), 
  mod_test_ui("column1"), 
  verbatimTextOutput("debug"),
  tags$script(src = "script.js")
)
```

#### server.R

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handler <- mod_test_server(
    id = "column1",
    numElems = reactive({ input$n })
  )
  output$debug <- renderPrint({ handler$getNames() })
}
```

#### R/mod_test_ui.R

```r
mod_test_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(id = ns("container"))
}
```

#### R/mod_test_server.R

```r
mod_test_server <- \(id, numElems) {
  moduleServer(
    id = id,
    module = \(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      # reactive to track added UI ids:
      rv_added_ids <- reactiveValues(ids = NULL)
      observeEvent(numElems(), {
        # do nothing if `numElems()` is less than zero:
        n <- numElems()
        if (n < 0) return()
        # remove previously rendered UIs:
        removeUI(
          selector = sprintf("#%s > *", ns("container")),
          multiple = TRUE,
          immediate = TRUE
        )
        # inform JS to set the removed input id values to NULL:
        lapply(rv_added_ids$ids, \(id) {
          session$sendCustomMessage(
            type = "set_to_null",
            list(id = id, value = NULL)
          )
        })
        # reset tracker:
        rv_added_ids$ids <- NULL
        # add new UIs:
        lapply(seq_len(n), \(i) {
          id <- ns(paste0("elem", i))
          # track new id:
          rv_added_ids$ids <- c(rv_added_ids$ids, id)
          insertUI(
            selector = paste0("#", ns("container")),
            where = "beforeEnd",
            ui = selectInput(
              inputId = id, 
              label = i,
              choices = LETTERS[sample(26, 3)]
            )
          )
        }
        )
      })
      getNames <- reactive(reactiveValuesToList(input))
      list(getNames = getNames)
    }
  )
}
```

#### www/script.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("set_to_null", (message) => {
    Shiny.setInputValue(message.id, message.value, {priority: "event"});
  });
});
```