remove_shiny_inputs not working for nested module
Background: I have an R shiny app where I use nested and dynamic modules. There are 3 nested levels:

App level module: where a data frame is created (not dynamic)

Tab level module: holds one feature of the app used to create custom data frame filters and view the data frame (not dynamic)

Filter level module: this is a dynamic module, meaning the user can create (or remove) as many filter modules as they need. I use insertUI() and removeUI() to accomplish this.


Problem: Whenever a filter level module is removed using removeUI(), you also need to remove the associated shiny inputs from the app's input object to avoid performance issues however I cannot figure out how to do this properly.
What I tried: I tried to accomplish this using a function named remove_shiny_inputs() from the demo by Jonas Hagenberg at Appsilon however it is not working.
I suspect the problem is related to the fact that I'm using nested modules with 3 levels and Jonas's example code only uses 2 levels. Note that due to other app requirements, I cannot modify the 3 level app architecture so I need to figure out how to remove_shiny_inputs() for my use case.
REPREX: I created the REPREX below with just the essentials. Note that the functionality of the app works perfectly fine. The problem is that when the user clicks "Remove last filter", the tab_server() module calls remove_shiny_inputs() however, if you inspect names(input) after doing this you will see that the inputs for the removed dynamic filter module are still there.
You can inspect this yourself with the browser() call I inserted in line 118. Duplicate the issue by clicking 'Add a filter' once, then click 'Remove last filter' once. This will open the interactive console due to the browser() call. Enter names(input) in the console and you will see the inputs id_1-column and id_1-filter1. After running remove_shiny_inputs(), call names(input) again and you will see that  id_1-column and id_1-filter1 still exist.
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

# use this R6 object to store filter info for all dynamic filter modules
filter_info_r6 <- R6::R6Class(
  classname = "filter_info",
  public = list(
    filters = list(),
    add_filter = function(id, col, val) {
      self$filters[[id]] <- list(
        col = col,
        val = val
      )
    },
    remove_filter = function(id) {
      self$filters[[id]] <- NULL
    }
  )
)

# remove shiny inputs after removeUI is called for a dynamic module
remove_shiny_inputs <- function(id, .input) {
  invisible(
    lapply(grep(id, names(.input), value = TRUE), function(i) {
      .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i)
    })
  )
}

# the outer most module contains the app
app_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Test Panel",
        tab_ui(ns("tab"))
      )
    )
  )
}

app_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      data1 <- data.frame(
        col_a = letters[1:3],
        col_b = letters[4:6]
      )
      
      tab_server("tab", data = data1)
    }
  )
}

# the middle module contains one tab in the app
tab_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      id = "filter_container"
    ),
    
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("add_filter"),
      label = "Add a filter"
    ),
    
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("remove_filter"),
      label = "Remove last filter"
    ),
    
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("apply_filters"),
      label = "Apply all filters"
    ),
    
    DTOutput(ns("datatable"))
  )
}

tab_server <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # create R6 object to tracker all filter info
      filter_info_r6_1 <- filter_info_r6$new()
      
      # create new filter module on button click
      observeEvent(input$add_filter, {
        
        current_id <- paste0("id_", input$add_filter)
        
        insertUI(
          selector = "#filter_container",
          ui = filter_ui(id = ns(current_id), cols = colnames(data))
        )
        
        filter_server(
          id = current_id,
          data = data,
          filter_info_storage = filter_info_r6_1
        )
        
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
      
      # remove last filter module on button click
      observeEvent(input$remove_filter, {
          
        browser()
        
        current_id <- names(filter_info_r6_1$filters)[length(filter_info_r6_1$filters)]
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#", ns(current_id)))
        
        # remove inputs
        remove_shiny_inputs(id = current_id, .input = input)
        
        # remove filter info from R6 object
        filter_info_r6_1$remove_filter(id = current_id)
        
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
      
      filtered_data <- reactiveVal(data)
      
      # apply all filters in the R6 object when apply filter button clicked
      observeEvent(input$apply_filters, {
        tmp_dat <- data
        for (filt in filter_info_r6_1$filters) {
          tmp_dat <- dplyr::filter(
            tmp_dat,
            !!rlang::sym(filt$col()) %in% filt$val()
          )
        }
        filtered_data(tmp_dat)
      })
      
      output$datatable <- renderDT({
        datatable(filtered_data())
      })
    }
  )
}

filter_ui <- function(id, cols) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tags$div(
    id = id,
    
    # select the column to filter
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("column"),
      label = "Select column to filter:",
      choices = cols,
      selected = cols[1]
    ),
    
    # reactively generated column filter values input
    uiOutput(ns("filters")),
    
    hr()
  )
}

filter_server <- function(id, data, filter_info_storage) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # render input based on type of column selected
      output$filters <- renderUI({
        
        all_col_vals <- sort(unique(data[[input$column]]))
        
        tagList(
          selectInput(
            inputId = ns("filter1"),
            label = "Select values to include:",
            choices = all_col_vals,
            selected = all_col_vals,
            multiple = TRUE
          )
        )
      })
      
      # add filter information to R6 filter info tracking object
      filter_info_storage$add_filter(
        id = id,
        col = reactive(input$column),
        val = reactive(input$filter1)
      )
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = app_ui("app"), 
         server = function(input, output, session) app_server("app"))


this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637957/update-input-in-module-with-dynamic-number-of-ui-elements

There were a couple of problems with your app.
This is a working remove_shiny_inputs function (comment on the changes below).
remove_shiny_inputs <- function(id, .input) {
  invisible({
    inp_fastmap <- .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values
    inp_rv <- .subset2(.input, "impl")
    lapply(grep(id, inp_fastmap$keys(), value = TRUE), inp_fastmap, inp_rv, FUN = function(i, fm, rv) {
      fm$remove(i)
      rv$.nameOrder <- fm$keys()
    })
  })
}

Namespacing problem
First of all, there was a small problem coming from the fact that your app uses nested modules. By using grep("id_1", .input, value = TRUE) you were not considering the namespacing that the module does for you. This expression returned for example the character vector c("id_1-filter1", "id_1-column"), but the actual input names were c("app-tab-id_1-filter1", "app-tab-id_1-column") due to the module nesting.
You can check this by printing the result of your .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i) call, and see that it prints NULL in your reprex. (As per shiny implementation, this method returns NULL when it fails)
To solve this issue, we can use the $keys() method on the input map object instead of names(input):
inp_fastmap <- .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values
(grep(id, inp_fastmap$keys(), value = TRUE)

Removing name from input object
Resolving the namespacing problem already gives you a working implementation of the remove_shiny_inputs function. However, if you were to print names(input) after the remove_shiny_inputs call, you would see that the removed input names would still be present in the list.
I was quite puzzled by this, so I dove in the shiny source code and found out that the input names are only updated when a new input is created, by adding the new key to the names list.
To solve this, we can access the underlying reactiveValues object via inp_rv <- .subset2(.input, "impl") and manually update the names with the fastmap keys after removing our input:
rv$.nameOrder <- fm$keys()

Final comment
This is a tricky workaround - it works, but I'm not sure it's 100% reliable.
Under the hood we are manipulating the shiny input implementation as a reactiveValues object, and the underlying fastmap manually. This could be "risky" behaviour.
I also have to say I found the reactiveValues implementation very interesting. If you want to understand what's going on here, the reactiveValues R6 class is basically based on a custom fastmap implementation, and builds on top of that to provide support for the various S3 generics. Sources: map.R, reactives.R.
